# How to go from intent to another in tab application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have tab based application. In one tab I have class that extends ListActivity. I need to another activity when an onClick is triggered while keeping the tab bar. I want to be transferred to another tab with an onClick while keeping the tab bar.

This code works but hide the tab bar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SectionContentList.class);   

// put values to intent which will get in the LoginSuccess    Activity
Log.d("",appState.MainCategories.get(position).get("feedUrl"));
intent.putExtra("FeedURL", appState.MainCategories.get(position).get("feedUrl"));

// Start LoginSuccess Activity
startActivity(intent);
```

How to transfer to this new intent while keeping the bottom tab bar?

Answer (score 2):

I have give u example for tab activity manage 
//There has declare number of tab Activity use there
package com.technosoft.Concina_Peru;

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.technosoft.FirstTab.FirstTab;
import com.technosoft.FourthTab.FourthTab;
import com.technosoft.SecondTab.SecondTab;
import com.technosoft.ThirdTab.ThirdTab;

public class ConcinaPeruTabbar extends TabActivity {

    public static Context tabContext;
    public static TabHost tabHost;
    Context con;
    public static String var = "";

    public static Concina_Database db;

    private void setupTabHost() {
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.starttab);
        tabContext = this;
        con = this.getApplicationContext();
        db = new Concina_Database(con);

        setupTabHost();
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Inicio");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Recetas");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Favoritos");
        setupTab(new TextView(this), "Mas");

    }



    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), tag);
        if(tag.equals("Inicio")){

            tabHost.addTab((tabHost.newTabSpec("Inicio")).setIndicator(
                    tabview).setContent(new Intent(this, FirstTab.class)));
        }
        if(tag.equals("Recetas")){

        tabHost.addTab((tabHost.newTabSpec("Recetas")).setIndicator(
                tabview).setContent(new Intent(this, SecondTab.class)));

        }
        if(tag.equals("Favoritos")){

            tabHost.addTab((tabHost.newTabSpec("Favoritos")).setIndicator(
                tabview).setContent(new Intent(this, ThirdTab.class)));

        }
        if(tag.equals("Mas")){

            tabHost.addTab((tabHost.newTabSpec("Mas")).setIndicator(
                tabview).setContent(new Intent(this, FourthTab.class)));

        }
    }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        if (text.equals("Inicio")) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_image);
        }
        if (text.equals("Recetas")) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_image1);
        }
        if (text.equals("Favoritos")) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_image2);
        }
        if (text.equals("Mas")) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_image3);
        }

        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

//First tab activity define here

```
public class FirstTab extends ActivityGroup{
    public static FirstTab group_FirstTab;

    private  ArrayList<View> history = new ArrayList<View>();
    ProgressDialog PD;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        group_FirstTab = this;
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CitiesAct", new
                Intent(FirstTab.this,Inicio.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
        replaceView(view);
    }
    public void replaceView(View view) {  

          history.add(view);
          setContentView(view);

      }
    public void RemoveView(){
         history.clear();

    }
    public void back(){
          if(history.size() > 1) {  
              history.remove(history.size()-1);  
              setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));

          }else{
              finish();
          }
      }

     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
     {              
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){                   
                group_FirstTab.back();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }


}
```

similar has another tab activity..
now u want to go to intent one tab to another  tab activity to another tab activity following code follow

for ex to want to gone 0 tab activity to 1 tab activity then use

```
tab activity Class tab_0{
    ConcinaPeruTabbar.tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); 
}
```

if u want to going one tab activty to simaar tab activty then use this 
    View view =

```
  FirstTab.group_FirstTab.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CitiesAct", new         Intent(Inicio.this,Platos.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).putExtra("platos", "Entradas")).getDecorView();
                    FirstTab.group_FirstTab.replaceView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented a tab bar, you have one Activity - let's call it MyTabActivity - that extends TabActivity.
In the `OnCreate(Bundle)` method of this Activity, you set up your tab bar by first retrieving the TabHost View in the XML :

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

To dynamically handle tab selection, you can keep the reference to TabHost as a static variable :

```
public static final TabHost tabHost;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabActivityLayout);
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    // ..... 
}
```

You can then access your TabHost from one of the tab Activities and set the current tab as below :

```
MyTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("the tag you affected to this activity");
```

OR

```
MyTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("the id you may have affected to it");
```

EDIT :
You affect the tag when affecting the tabs to the TabHost as follow :

```
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("The Tag").setIndicator(tabView).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I have class that extends ListActivity , I need when on one of its item click to show another activity with keeping the tab bar

Comment: I don't see the contradiction, your ListActivity is one of the tab acivities right?
ie, you did this in the OnCreate() of your TabActivity :

`TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Your ListActivity Tag").setIndicator(tabView).setContent(The intent launching your ListActivity);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);`

Comment: You can do the following in your ListActivity, in its
[protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long))
:
 
`MyTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("the tag you affected to the activity you want to go to");`

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments to share portions of UI between many Activities.